# Database connection

Tags: database, linq-to-sql

I have a WinForms project, which consists of 10 forms. Forms are called to each other, each shape is drawn to the database 
(I'm using LINQ to SQL) how best to create a database connection, I set up the connection when loading the main form

```
string path = "Data Source = | DataDirectory | \ \ Database.sdf"; 
Database db = new Database (path);
```

and then loading each window is transmitted through an object constructor db, then work with the database,

```
Window1 win1 = new Window1(db)
```

there may be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use static class for your db operations.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, you should abstract your database logic / connections into their own class or assembly. The connection string shouldn't be hard coded, but come from the app.config file.

I don't think you should be passing around the connection object.

As I stated above, abstract our your database code and wrap your the context in a Using statement.